# Double LinkedList Deep Copy in Kotlin

Tags: linked-list, kotlin

## Goal

- Return a deep copy of a double LinkedList.
- Each node also contains an additional random pointer, potentially to any node or null.

## Code to start

```kotlin
data class Node<T>(
    var data: T?,
    var previous: Node<T>? = null,
    var next: Node<T>? = null,
    var random: Node<T>? = null

class LinkedList {
    // TODO: Implement deep copy here.
}
```

## Implement

```kotlin
fun main() {
    // Setup
    val node1 = Node(1)
    val node2 = Node(2)
    val node3 = Node(3)
    node1.next = node2
    node1.random = node3
    node2.previous = node1
    node2.next = node3
    node3.previous = node2
    node3.random = node1

    val linkedList = LinkedList()
    val deepCopy = linkedList.nextDeepCopy(node1)
    // LinkedList data changed.
    node1.data = 101
    node2.data = 202
    node3.data = 303
    val shallowCopy = linkedList.shallowCopy(node1)
    println("Deep copy made")
    linkedList.print(deepCopy)
    println()
    println("Shallow copy made")
    linkedList.print(shallowCopy)
}

data class Node<T>(
        var data: T?,
        var previous: Node<T>? = null,
        var next: Node<T>? = null,
        var random: Node<T>? = null
)

class LinkedList {
    fun <T> nextDeepCopy(node: Node<T>?): Node<T>? {
        if (node != null) {
            return Node(
                    data = node.data,
                    previous = newDeepCopy(node.previous),
                    next = nextDeepCopy(node.next),
                    random = newDeepCopy(node.random)
            )
        } else return null
    }

    fun <T> newDeepCopy(node: Node<T>?): Node<T>? {
        if (node != null) {
            return Node(
                    data = node.data,
                    previous = node.previous,
                    next = node.next,
                    random = node.random
            )
        } else return null
    }

    fun <T> shallowCopy(node: Node<T>?) = node!!.copy()

    fun <T> print(node: Node<T>?){
        if (node != null){
            println("Node data:${node.data} previous:${node.previous?.data} next:${node.next?.data} random:${node.random?.data}")
            print(node.next)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your latest edit has made this question off-topic as the code does not work as intended. Please can you remove your 'answer' that was previously in the question and add it back into the question.

Comment: I've made the suggested recommendation above re-adding the code. The question seems to be on-topic without the sample code as the question is asking the optimal implementation of a Double LinkedList deep copy in Kotlin. Therefore, it seems appropriate to include the code as an answer vs. in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Misplaced Responsibility: `print()`

The `class LinkedList` (or `data class Node`, see below) should not `print()` functions.
Calling `print()` functions is a separate responsibility and should be done elsewhere in the code:
What if you want your program to support different output formats like JSON or XML and they shall be sent over the network?
Of course, we don't prepare software for all what-ifs.
But we do make the obvious "cuts" between responsibilities.
To get a printable representation, extract the text used by the `print()` calls into a `toString()` method.
Then call `print(node)` from `main()`.

## Avoid Feature Envy (from `LinkedList` on `Node`)

*Feature Envy* is a special type of Misplaced Responsibility.
The `class LinkedList` doesn't have any features of its own, and no state.
Instead, it only operates on everything in the `data class Node`.
This is a design smell that we call *Feature Envy*.
Move all the methods from the `class LinkedList` to the `data class Node`.
Then remove the `class LinkedList`.

You will notice that when you fix *Feature Envy* problems, the lines become shorter: References that have to wander around because of the Feature Envy become the omittable `this`.

There are situations where this type of Feature Envy is justified:
In cases of specific design patterns like Proxy, Delegate, Facade.

The `class LinkedList` does not qualify as a *Facade* because it exposes the type `Node<T>`.
It would only qualify if its type `Node<T>` would be hidden from the user, and the only other type the user sees were `<T>`.

The sitaution would, of course, change once you give `class LinkedList` fields `head` and `tail`.

## Avoid error-prone interfaces

The current interface is error-prone.
It allows for broken linked lists.
The fields `next` and `previous` should be read-only for the user of `Node`.
Instead, the user of `Node` should have to go through a method like `insertAfter()`, `insertBefore()`, `delete()`.
After all, insertion and deletion are not atomic operations but should be transactions.
As a next step, you could ponder about the thread-safety of these operations.

## Avoid exposing implementation detail

That a LinkedList is implemented with Nodes is an implementation detail that the user doesn't need to know.
The user should be able to focus on the primary purposes of LinkedLists:

- Payload (data)
- Iteration/Traversal
- Insertion and Removal
  Your interface is too low-level.

The perfect `LinkedList` interface is (almost?) indistiguishable from an `ArrayList` interface. It should be possible to swap one implementation, like `LinkedList`, for another, like `ArrayList`, due to performance considerations (*O(1)* random access for `ArrayList`, *O(n/2)* random access for `LinkedList` vs *O(1)* insert/delete for `LinkedList`, *O(n/2)* insert/delete for `ArrayList`) without having to change all the code that uses the list.

## Null-Checking

Only use `Type?` if you really need to support nullability.
I recommend to use `Type` instead of `Type?` whereever you can.
That the Kotlin compiler can enforce NonNull is one of the many strengths that it has over Java.
Don't squander it by making everything nullable with `?`.

## BUG: `fun nextDeepCopy()` doesn't create a deep copy

It doesn't, because it doesn't recurse to itself but calls `newDeepCopy()`, and that is not recursive.

The correct way to create a deep copy of a LinkedList with additional random pointers would be to

1. Create a map with the old nodes as key and the new node as value.
2. Loop over the map, setting the pointers of the new nodes by a lookup in the map.
   Traditional ways of copying a LinkedList won't work because of the random pointer.

Also, `fun newDeepCopy()` does exactly the same thing as the built-in `fun copy()`, it creates a shallow copy of the current object.

## Unit Tests?

There are ways how to prevent bugs like the one above.
I recommend writing unit tests.
Even better, use Test-Driven Development.

## Use `if`-expressions

In Kotlin, `if` is an expression.
You can make use of it.

The code:

```
if (condition) return a else return b
```

can also be written as, more idiomatic:

```
return if (condition) a else b
```

This would allow for all of your functions to become expression functions.

## Piece of Sample Code

Here's a code snippet to show how your code could look like:

```
data class Node<T>(
        var data: T?,
        var previous: Node<T>? = null,
        var next: Node<T>? = null,
        var random: Node<T>? = null
) {
    fun shallowCopy() = copy() // You could even omit this
    fun deepCopy(): Node<T> = TODO("Implement this")
    fun toString() = "Node data:${data} previous:${previous?.data} next:${next?.data} random:${random?.data}"
}
```

Comment: Very small remark: instead of the if-expression, `let` or `run` offers an even more compact solution, `node?.run { Node(data, previous, next, random) }` given that you don't go for the even simpler option: `node?.copy()`

Comment: Thank you for the thorough code review @Christian Hujer! I will post a new answer with the `nextDeepCopy()` bug fix, and then I will continue to refactor based on the additional notes above.

Comment: @tieskedh, Good point. I've found for myself it can be easy to get carried away with too much nesting using the accessor extension functions so I try to be cognizant based on the use case.

Comment: you're right. I'm less restricted in frequency, but more on the nesting-level: almost never more than one extension-scope function and I choose for the not-extension scope function unless there's a good reason.