# Double LinkedList Deep Copy in Kotlin with Generics and Thread Safety

Tags: multithreading, linked-list, thread-safety, generics, kotlin

## Goal

- Return a deep copy of a double LinkedList.
- Each node also contains an additional random pointer, potentially to any node or null.

## Code to start

```kotlin
data class Node<T>(
    var data: T?,
    var previous: Node<T>? = null,
    var next: Node<T>? = null,
    var random: Node<T>? = null

class LinkedList {
    // TODO: Implement deep copy here.
}
```

## Questions

- Generics - Is there a better approach to handle the generic variance as to not need `as T` when passing in a generic type? i.e. `linkedList.add(data = 1 as T)`
- *Add thread-safety for operations* - Are there any specific recommendations on thread-safety for this solution or broader topics to research to understand thread-safety considerations further?

## Implement

**See the [*full code on GitHub*](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/DSA-LC-LinkedList-DeepCopy).**

*LinkedList.kt*

```kotlin
class Node<T>(
        var prev: Node<T>? = null,
        var next: Node<T>? = null,
        var rand: Node<T>? = null,
        var data: T
)

class LinkedList<T>(
        var first: Node<T>? = null,
        var last: Node<T>? = null,
        val randMap: HashMap<Node<T>?, Node<T>?> = hashMapOf()
) {
    // Add Node to the end of LinkedList
    fun add(data: T): Node<T> {
        val temp = last
        val newNode = Node(prev = temp, data = data)
        last = newNode
        if (temp == null)
            first = newNode
        else
            temp.next = newNode
        return newNode
    }

    fun deepCopyWithoutRandoms(prev: Node<T>?, node: Node<T>?): Node<T>? {
        return if (node == null)
            null
        else {
            val newNode = Node(data = node.data)
            if (node.rand != null) {
                newNode.rand = node.rand
                randMap.put(node.rand, null)
            }
            newNode.prev = prev
            newNode.next = deepCopyWithoutRandoms(newNode, node.next)
            if (randMap.containsKey(node))
                randMap.put(node, newNode)
            return newNode
        }
    }

    fun updateRandoms(node: Node<T>?): Node<T>? {
        if (node != null) {
            if (node.rand != null)
                node.rand = randMap.get(node.rand!!)
            updateRandoms(node.next)
            return node
        } else return null
    }

    fun clear() {
        var node = first
        while (node != null) {
            node.prev = null
            node.next = null
            node.rand = null
            node.data = 0 as T
            node = node.next
        }
    }

    fun toString(first: Node<T>?): String {
        var output = ""
        var node = first
        while (node != null) {
            output += String.format("(prev:%s next:%s data:%s random:%s)\n", node.prev, node.next, node.data, node.rand)
            node = node.next
        }
        return output
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Double LinkedList Deep Copy in Kotlin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244600/double-linkedlist-deep-copy-in-kotlin)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @CarsonGraham. The linked question does not answer the question above as it does not cover the topics of Generics and Thread Safety.

Comment: ah, I see now. Give me a minute

Comment: This question ended up in the close vote queue as a duplicate of the original, which it wasn't. When you ask a follow up question to something closely related I recommend you provide a link to the original question as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to touch on your question on thread safety as it is a broad topic I am not familiar with. However, I can help with your questions about generics.

Right now, you're using generics great, except in one single place

```
node.data = 0 as T
```

The type of `node.data` is `T`. This code will fail if `T` is not `Int` - for example, if `T` is `String`, the code will look like this:

```
node.data = 0 as String
```

and that will throw a runtime exception.

Here's the important thing, though. There's no reason to do `node.data = <anything>`.
I assume the reason for having it originally was to "zero out" or get rid of the data as it's removed from the list - but that's what java will do for you automatically!

Let's say you have the following structure

```
linked list    /--> node 1   /--> value 1
-----------    |    ------   |    --------
first node ---/     data ---/        7
```

when you delete the pointer to `node 1`, you end up in this situation

```
linked list         node 1   /--> value 1
-----------         ------   |    --------
first node->null    data ---/        7
```

now that there is no reference anywhere to `node 1`, the jvm garbage collector deletes it

```
linked list         value 1
-----------         ------
first node->null        7
```

and because there is no reference to `value 1`, it's also deallocated.

This means that there's no reason to set the data field to anything - and, besides the point, there is no possible value you could set it to that would work for any value of T (in java, though, you could use null)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response regarding generic usage _@Carson Graham_.  I've refactored the `clear` function in this _[commit](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/DSA-LC-LinkedList-DeepCopy/commit/40ad5bd2f735a49297d8c3fd1f79f3ed6d78069d)_ to not "zero out" the data as the Java garbage collection will delete unreferenced resources as you outlined.